# Receiving and verifying the response from a webhook

Tags: php, webhooks, typeform

I am using typeform and for fetch the results i am using typeform's webhook. After a research i get to know the way to fetch response from webhook using PHP.

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$action = json_decode($json, true);
```

Now my questions are,

1. How to verify if the response is sent by typeform only? as typeform containing a filed stripe payment, so i want to implement security and verify the data before saving to the database.
2. Is it really a standrad way to fetch response from webhook, as i oubt Zend use http stream for that. So what is the way to fetch response from a webhook.

I researched for it but only found the way which i mentioned above.